# How can I find a string based on a specific word, between two specific words?

Tags: python, regex

New to Regex, please help!

Example String:

```
START

  blahblah
  blahblah blahblah
  blahblahblahblah

  blahblah KEYWORD blah

  blahblah
  blah

END
```

Problem: I would like to locate the entire string (between START and END) containing a certain KEYWORD.

Context: I have a large file with multiple iterations of the multi-line START*END example string and need to sort these strings based on the KEYWORD they contain. Each string contains the same START and END, but a different KEYWORD.

What I have so far:

```
START\s[\s\S]*?(?=END\s|\Z)    returns the entire string, but is not specific to a KEYWORD
```

Not sure how to go about finding the entire string based on the KEYWORD.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you distinguish the keyword from the surrounding blahblah? Is the blahblah always exactly the same? Is there a fixed list of possible keywords?

Comment: blahblah is different in each string. Think of blahblah as random characters, whitespaces, newlines, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?s)(?<=START)(?:(?!END).)*?(?:KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2)(?:.*?)(?=END)
```

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/F4oahz/2)) Firstly - we consider a newline as "any character". We start just after `START`, and end just before `END`. In between, we want as low number of any characters that don't start the string `END` as possible, followed by `KEYWORD1` or `KEYWORD2`, followed by as low number of any characters as possible.

This is based on the assumption that you have a finite list of keywords. If, on the other hand, keywords are identified by some other means, then you should Michael Butscher's comment first.